# Flutter, I am using local_auth 0.6.3+2 for Touch ID, Face ID authentication. but can not find how to turn on Enter Passcode button

Tags: flutter, passcode

Flutter, I am using local_auth 0.6.3+2 for Touch ID, Face ID authentication. but can not find how to turn on Enter Passcode button.

So users may try maximum 6 times of unrecognized Face ID to make it unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS **does not allow** application to access system PIN/passcode for security reason. Only bio-metric like fingerprint or facial recognition is allowed since that is secondary security measure for the system.

If you need to implement PIN/passcode, you would need to implement in on your own and store it within your system.